# How do you make a div wrap around floating elements?

Tags: html, css

**What I want**

I am trying to create a navigation bar for a mobile site. I want a dark blue navigation div to house a menu button and a search form.

**What I get**

My wrapper div just appears as a thin dark blue line and the navigation divs within just exist outside of the wrapper.

**The code**

```
<div id="mobileNavBar">

    <div style="float:left;width:20%">
        <span class="menu-trigger"><i class="fas fa-bars menuFA fa-2x"></i> 
        </span>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;width:80%"> 
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS for the navigation div

```
#mobileNavBar{
        background-color: #4d94ff; 
        border:1px solid #4d94ff;
        height:auto;
    }
```

**The image**

Below is an image of my mobile site, ignore the large black boxes, that's just me hiding content. There's actually a logo there and written content.

As you can see, my navigation div is a thin darker blue line and the navigation contents are underneath.

[image: Mobile Site]

**What I tried**

Well after looking at similar questions on this website, I was led to believe that the issue is that my elements are floating and therefore I need to add:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

However this doesn't seem to have an impact.

How, could I get the navigation div to wrap itself around the image for the menu and the search bar? Or rather, how do I get a div to wrap around floating divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CSS hack for clearing all your internal floats.
Add class "clearfix" to your div:

```
<div id="mobileNavBar" class="clearfix">

  <div style="float:left;width:20%">
    <span class="menu-trigger"><i class="fas fa-bars menuFA fa-2x"></i> 
    </span>
  </div>

  <div style="float:right;width:80%"> 
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.clearfix {
   overflow: auto;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

So, this will clear all the floats inside an existing div.
You could have created style with your div id 'mobileNavBar' as well but it is better to create a reusable class.

Please check https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp for more clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and more importantly for the link, reading this helps me get a better understanding of "why?" which will be useful in future situations!

Answer (score 1):

Apply following class to floated elements parent.

```
.clear:after{
   content: ' ';
   display: table;
   clear: both
}
```

Or you can add extra element in HTML

```
<div> 
  <div style="float: left;">Sidebar</div> 
 <div style="float: right;">Content</div> 
  <div style="clear: both;"></div><!-- Clear the float -->
 </div>
```

above solution solve your problem but my opinion is you can use **flex** to **grid** for this kind of layout.

Answer (score 1):

Floats can be tricky. Can you use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

`display:flex` will make this simpler :)

css:

```
#mobileNavBar {
    background-color: #4d94ff;
    border: 1px solid #4d94ff;
    display: flex;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="mobileNavBar">
    <div style="width:20%;">
        <span class="menu-trigger"><i class="fas fa-bars menuFA fa-2x">first div</i></span>
    </div>
    <div style="width:80%">
        second div
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
* markup for outline and padding not shown